# Get the age of a file in the terms of commits in git

Tags: python, git

I want to get some metrics on which files in my repository are the most recently active, using a measurement that does not require any calculation after storage. Thus number of commits ago that it was last modified.

So the idea that I have is thus:

```
file_list = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'ls-files'])
(files, _) = proc.communicate()

missing_ages = files
ages = {f: -1 for f in old_ages}

commits_proc = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'ref-list', '--all', '--pretty=format:""'])
(commits, _) = commits_proc.communicate()
age = 0

for commit_sha in [s.split(' ')[1] for s in commits]
    commit_list = subprocess.Popen('some', 'git', 'command')
    commit_files = commit_list.communicate()

    for file in commit_files
        if file in missing_ages
            ages[file] = age
            missing_ages.remove(file)
     age += 1
```

What I need is a non-porcelain git command to get the list of files in a commit given its sha.

Comment: Isn't the entire file tree referenced by each git commit? You'll need to diff adjacent commits to determine if a file changed,

Comment: This is true, however there is, for example `git show --stat <commitish>` which is able to list the files changes in a commit, but it is not stable, and also includes extra information that I would rather not parse out

Comment: `git show` simply does a diff of the commit against its parent(s) (combined diff if merge with multiple parents).  You must do the same thing (perhaps having git do it for you, e.g., `git diff-tree --name-status`) to detect changes.

Comment: Thanks, but what command would give me a list of all the files that are touched by the commit (added, modified, moved or have access or type changed)

Answer (score 0):

> `git show --stat <commitish>` which is able to list the files changes in a commit, but it is not stable,

It can be stable, with the `--porcelain` option:

> Use a special line-based format **intended for script consumption**.
>   Added/removed/unchanged runs are printed in the usual unified diff format, starting with a `+/-/` character at the beginning of the line and extending to the end of the line.
>   Newlines in the input are represented by a tilde `~` on a line of its own.

You would still need to do some parsing though.

Answer (score 0):

The final solution was to use `git diff-tree -z --name-only --no-commit-id -r <sha>`.

Source: the question asker EdJoJob [had edited the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32597811/4) to include this.